# Удалить элемент из динамического массива

Tags: c++

Вот код:

```
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    srand(time(NULL));

    cout << "Введите количество элементов в массиве: ";
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int *massiv = new int[size];

    cout << "Введите диапозон чисел в массиве: ";
    int diapozon_v_massive;
    cin >> diapozon_v_massive;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        massiv[i] = rand() % diapozon_v_massive;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << massiv[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "Введите минимальное значение интервала удаление значений: ";
    int interval_min;
    cin >> interval_min;
    cout << "Введите максимальное значение интервала удаление значений: ";
    int interval_max;
    cin >> interval_max;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (interval_max >= massiv[i] >= interval_min) {
            delete [] massiv[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << massiv[i] << endl;
    }

    delete[] massiv;
}
```

нужно удалить элемент массива, попадающий в интервал, который задаёт пользователь. Через delete и delete [] не получается. Подскажите как ещё можно сделать?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "удалить элемент массива"? Задайте себе простой вопрос -- что должно быть на его месте после удаления? Как это "пустое место" будет выглядеть, если после удаления вы в цикле будете читать все элементы? Понятно, что такое невозможно. Удалить элемент можно либо логически, записав на это место константу, которая никогда не может быть в ваших данных, либо сдвинув все элементы после удаленного на одну позицию к началу массива (т.о. вы уменьшите фактический размер (но не занимаемую память) массива). Как именно стоит поступать, зависит от смысла задачи

Comment: `std::vector` не хотите?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C++ нет прямого способа удалить элемент из динамического массива. Оператор delete используется для освобождения памяти, выделенной через new, и не может использоваться для удаления отдельных элементов массива.

Вместо этого, ты можешь создать новый массив, который будет содержать только те элементы, которые не попадают в заданный интервал. Вот как это можно сделать:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    srand(time(NULL));

    cout << "Введите количество элементов в массиве: ";
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int *massiv = new int[size];

    cout << "Введите диапозон чисел в массиве: ";
    int diapozon_v_massive;
    cin >> diapozon_v_massive;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        massiv[i] = rand() % diapozon_v_massive;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << massiv[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "Введите минимальное значение интервала удаление значений: ";
    int interval_min;
    cin >> interval_min;
    cout << "Введите максимальное значение интервала удаление значений: ";
    int interval_max;
    cin >> interval_max;

    int newSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (!(massiv[i] >= interval_min && massiv[i] <= interval_max)) {
            newSize++;
        }
    }

    int *newMassiv = new int[newSize];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (!(massiv[i] >= interval_min && massiv[i] <= interval_max)) {
            newMassiv[j] = massiv[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    delete[] massiv;
    massiv = newMassiv;
    size = newSize;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << massiv[i] << endl;
    }

    delete[] massiv;
}
```

В этом коде мы сначала подсчитываем количество элементов, которые не попадают в заданный интервал, затем создаем новый массив этого размера и заполняем его этими элементами. Затем мы удаляем старый массив и заменяем его новым.

Comment: Возможно для подобных задач (с plain типами) лучше подойдут malloc/realloc

Comment: Подскажите, что значит ! перед условием оператора if?